# deftype failing in lein repl what am I doing wrong?

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop, deftype, leiningen

Per http://www.assembla.com/spaces/clojure/wiki/Datatypes

I should be able to type the following into a lein reply:

> (deftype Bar [a b c d e])
>
> (def b (Bar 1 2 3 4 5))

However when I do I get the following output:

> java.lang.Exception: Expecting var, but Bar is mapped to class user.Bar (NO_SOURCE_FILE:31)

I'm confused and am a complete newb to clojure all help is appreciated!

NOTE: Tried same code in standard clojure repl and get same problem.

ANSWER: Well I answered my own question with a little additional searching.  Turns out the sample was bad.  The correct way to instantiate Bar would be:

> (def b (Bar. 1 2 3 4 5))

The . at the end of Bar in that usage is important.  Still don't quite understand why (so you clojure experts please elaborate if you have time since I would like to know the details ;) ).

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The assembla site is obsolete. Furthermore this were design documents which are by nature volatile and might get out-of-date pretty quick. Check http://clojure.org and http://clojure.github.com/clojure for up-to-date documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not that familiar with `deftype`, but from what I see you need a point to instantiate a type, try this:

```
(deftype Bar [a b c d e])

(def b (Bar. 1 2 3 4 5))
```

Note it's not `Bar`, but `Bar.`. See examples e.g. here:

- http://pastebin.com/9vqPpebT
- http://onclojure.com/2010/08/26/reusable-method-implementations-for-deftypes/ (which uses `(new foo ...)` instead of `(foo. ...)`)

This thread seems to indicate this was a change in `deftype`:

- http://osdir.com/ml/clojure/2010-04/msg00526.html

or, to put it the other way around, the docs on the page you link to seem outdated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways of achieving what you are attempting to do.  First, let's go over the    `deftype` example.

```
user=> (deftype Bar [a b c d e])
user.Bar
user=> (def b (Bar. 1 2 3 4 5))
#'user/b
user=> (:a b)
nil
user=> (.a b)
1
```

You'll notice a few things, here.  As was mentioned, you need the "." to instantiate your type.  Furthermore, you don't get keyword access (":" notation), only field access (again, with a ".").

The other method is by defining a record with    `defrecord`:

```
user=> (defrecord Bar [a b c d e])
user.Bar
user=> (def b (Bar. 1 3 5 7 9))
#'user/b
user=> (:a b)
1
user=> (.a b)
1
```

This gives you both field and keyword access.  This access is easily nested, as well, should you decide to have one of your fields contain another record.